# Universe in Business Objects is Equivalent of Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-objects

In Business Objects, you need to select a Universe before you can run queries.  Is this the same grouping of data as a database in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially correct.  The layers inside BusinessObjects are Report - Universe - Database.  So when you select a Universe that Universe actually has a database selected with in it called a Connection in BusinessObjects terminology.

The Universe allows more business focused view of the database.  This means that business terms can be used for objects that are used in the reports with out the report builder knowing how the database is actually designed.  The other big benefit is that you can change the Universe's Connection so that it uses a different database without needing to update or change the reports.

Through XI R3.x a Universe may only be connected to one database. I am unsure about XI R4.x since my company has yet to migrate to it.

A report may have 2 or more different universes associated to it, though merging the 2 dataset together can be a little finicky.

Comment: Thanks.  Can a universe be connected to more than one database at a time?